# LitElement shadow root after styles loaded event

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, lit-element, lit-html

I have a problem, I need to handle event after CSS styles was loaded into my component. I was trying to use lit-element lifecycle, still they are fired to early.

I'm trying to get my DOM element starting position and other data, but I get an initial position where after styles is loaded this position changes?

How to make styles load first or any event after styles loaded?

Answer (score 2):

The [firstUpdated](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/lifecycle#firstupdated) lifecycle is typically what you're looking for:

> Called after the element’s DOM has been updated the first time, immediately before updated is called.
>   Implement firstUpdated to perform one-time work after the element’s template has been created.

If your elements are still loading even after `firstUpdated` is fired, you could wait for another cycle just to be safe with:

```
setTimeout(() => { /* code for checking DOM styles */ }, timeInMilliseconds);
```

`timeInMilliseconds` will likely only need to be `0`, but you may need to give it a bit more time because your styles are changing outside of typical styles.  This could also be the case if you have any CSS `animation` or `transition` that could be impacting the display of your elements.

If all the above looks correct, I recommend opening an issue on the [lit-element github page](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element/issues) as it's still actively contributed to.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of specifically how to wait for and element's styles to be loaded.

Comment: @trusktr that wasn't the question that was asked.  If you want, you are able to start a new question specifically around what you are looking for.